# AWS Website Images not loading

Tags: html, amazon-web-services

I manage a website for a school magazine and I have been doing some work on it, however I have noticed that suddenly some of the images are not loading and giving error 404 messages when just a day ago it was working fine. I thought it might just be my web browser (chrome) and so I tried changing the browser and used edge and while some of the pictures loaded when they did not before some other ones now did not load.

The website is hosted on AWS using elastic beanstalk and S3. Here is a link to the website: [Ink Magazine](http://inkstudents.co.uk/)

Here are some pictures of the problems I am getting:

[Ink Featured Missing Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzcuX.png)

Any insight into why this is happening would be greatly appriciated, I have checked and the images are still on the S3 server and can be downloaded and opened fine, plus the same images still work when the article is opened.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image URLs look weird to me. For example this:

`http://inkstudents.co.uk/image/pictureThumbnail-photos-from-the-royal-visit.png/true/x2016-06-19T20,3A13,3A49Z.pagespeed.ic.EdDYAbdtI_.webp`

If I remove everything after the `.png` then the image loads, like this:

`http://inkstudents.co.uk/image/pictureThumbnail-photos-from-the-royal-visit.png`

It looks like you may have tried adding Google PageSpeed to your site, but it isn't configured properly?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I did not know that the website was using pagespeed but it appears someone changed a setting to try and turn pagespeed off and that seemed to break the images I changed pagespeed and all the images appear to be working again.